# Why is there no QTransform::fromRotate?

Tags: c++, qt5

Qt's QTransform offers some more optimized ways to construct a translated/scaled QTransform matrix using these static methods:

- [QTransform::fromScale](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#fromScale)
- [QTransform::fromTranslate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#fromTranslate)

Now I need a rotatated transform and I thought it would be nice to also have a `QTransform::fromRotate`. But this one does not exist.

In my case I am modifying a existing transform accordingly to mouse interaction like paning, zooming and also rotating.

```
void MapDrawingItem::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)
{
    //Moving the hovered point to the top left point on screen
    m_view_transform *= QTransform::fromTranslate(-event->posF().x(), -event->posF().y());

    //Apply transformations accordingly
    if((event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) == Qt::ControlModifier)
        m_view_transform *= QTransform().rotate(event->delta() / 30.);
    else
    {
        auto factor = qPow(1.001, event->delta());
        m_view_transform *= QTransform::fromScale(factor, factor);
    }

    //Move the hovered point back to the mouse cursor
    m_view_transform *= QTransform::fromTranslate(event->posF().x(), event->posF().y());

    emit signalViewTransformChanged(m_view_transform);
    update();
}
```

The code works correctly, but I would like to replace the `QTransform().rotate(...)` with a `QTransform::fromRotate(...)`

Why does this method not exist already? I just can't imagine the Qt developers forgot for this one. Is there anything that makes this impossible?

Comment: it's normal to implement only what is needed.... you probably can propose that, but I think there's some implementation issue in relation to that.  Probably you cannot reuse the same matrix for different rotations and you have to use a nonstatic instance.  But QT is opensource, so probably you can dig in the source code to get an idea of why they implemented that another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable reason for that is that creating and using a static function to create a rotation transformation forces to always link the mathematical library (for the `sin(3)` and `cos(3)` mathematical functions) so instead you can use the specific constructor for that and use them yourself.

By the way, you can use one of the constructors to specify the constants to use for the elements of the matrix.  I'ts quite common to conserve the matrices for reuse when using the transformations library.